# Android java app installation under the hood

Tags: java, android, installation, package, apk

I am trying to understand what exactly is going on when you install an application (APK) on an Android device. I guess that files are are extracted from the package and copied somewhere on the device.

- Are there other steps going on? For example, is the package name of the application written somewhere in the OS like in somekind of registry?
- Is the application version number written as well somewhere or the OS reads the xml manifest of the application to know its installed version?

This is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677957/android-app-with-specific-package-name-cannot-install) where I suspect that some data was not erased correctly during the uninstallation of a debug app and I am trying to find what that might be.

Comment: Yes.. Not just in Android OS but in every OS, you need to have a registry. In case of Android OS, sometimes the entire data/config of the app will not be erased. You will have to do some kind of memory flashing/clearing for such sotuations.

Comment: Why close vote? I think it is related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be files/dirs created in various locations, not necessary in all possible locations for every app though, it depends on how the app is configured.

This list is not necessarily complete.

Files/dirs:

- /data/data
- /data/app
- /data/app-asec
- /data/app-lib
- /data/dalvik-cache
- /data/local/tmp
- /mnt/asec
- /mnt/obb
- /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb
- /mnt/sdcard/Android/data

Your app will also get an entry in these files:

- /data/system/packages.list
- /data/system/packages.xml
- /data/system/appops.xml